# Python C-API and PyRun_File: Using "import functools and partial(print, flush=True)"

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

First a short background:

(1) When running this program in Python3.6 I need to wait until it ends for the result to be displayed:

```
import time

for i in range(5):
        print(i, end=" ")
        time.sleep(1)
```

(2) This program on the other hand works as I would like it to, each value printed every second:

```
import time

import functools
print = functools.partial(print, flush=True)

for i in range(5):
        print(i, end=" ")
        time.sleep(1)
```

And now to my question:

How can I add

```
import functools
print = functools.partial(print, flush=True)
```

in C code so that I can run program 1 using PyRun_File, but have the results as if I was running program 2?

I have had trouble finding documentation and examples that is straight forward and easy to understand, so I'm hoping for some help.

This is what I have tried (error checking omitted and old code already in the program I'm trying to improve is labeled "//existing"):

```
Py_Initialize(); //existing

PyObject* functools = PyImport_ImportModule("functools");
PyObject* partial = PyObject_GetAttrString(functools, "partial");

PyObject* builtins = PyImport_ImportModule("builtins");
PyObject* print = PyObject_GetAttrString(builtins, "print");

PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(1);
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, print);

PyObject* kwargs = PyDict_New();
PyDict_SetItemString(kwargs, "flush", Py_True);

PyObject_Call(partial, args, kwargs);

PyObject* main_module = PyImport_ImportModule("__main__"); //existing
PyObject* pdict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module); //existing

FILE* fp = fopen("prg_1.py", "r"); //existing
PyObject* pval = PyRun_File(fp, "prg_1.py", Py_file_input, pdict, pdict); //existing

Py_Finalize(); //existing
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as I hoped it would, so can anyone spot any obvious errors, or maybe not so obvious ones?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: For **every** function that returns a `PyObject*` you should check if the return value is `NULL`. If it is then your need something like `PyErr_Print` to investigate why. This'll help you figure our what's gone wrong. It's probably an issue with the module search path (but that'll be a lot clearer if you knew where it's failing)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @DavidW. As I wrote, I have deliberately omitted error handling in the posted code to make it clearer. In reality I have of course checked for NULL and the code "work" in that sense, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `PyObject_Call` has a return value?

Comment: Yes. tp_name is "functools.partial", and there are other tp_-values as well which all seem to be ok.

And as a sidenote:
PyRun_SimpleString("import functools");
PyRun_SimpleString("print = functools.partial(print, flush=True)");
and then calling PyRun_File seems to work.

Comment: The point I was making is that just calling `functools.partial(print, flash=True)` doesn't replace `print` - instead it returns a function that you can call instead.

Comment: That actually sounds very reasonable, @DavidW. Thank you! :o) So in the code from my original question, if I save the return value from the PyObject_Call, how does one make this returned print function to be used when executing Python code in the PyRun_File?

Comment: I think if you add it to `pdict` (as `print`) it should be found instead of `print`. Although that probably affects all subsequent uses of the `__main__` module

Comment: `PyObject* newPrint = PyObject_Call(partial, args, kwargs);` and then `PyDict_SetItemString(pdict, "print", newPrint);` seems to work, but will do some more testing tomorrow. Thank you very much for your help, @DavidW!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the valuable input from DavidW it now works! Thank you!

(I did although encounter another problem which I will address in a new question.)

With additions the code now looks like this (error checking is still omitted):

```
Py_Initialize(); //existing

PyObject* functools = PyImport_ImportModule("functools");
PyObject* partial = PyObject_GetAttrString(functools, "partial");

PyObject* builtins = PyImport_ImportModule("builtins");
PyObject* print = PyObject_GetAttrString(builtins, "print");

PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(1);
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, print);

PyObject* kwargs = PyDict_New();
PyDict_SetItemString(kwargs, "flush", Py_True);

PyObject* newPrint = PyObject_Call(partial, args, kwargs);

PyObject* main_module = PyImport_ImportModule("__main__"); //existing
PyObject* pdict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module); //existing

PyDict_SetItemString(pdict, "print", newPrint);

FILE* fp = fopen("prg_1.py", "r"); //existing
PyObject* pval = PyRun_File(fp, "prg_1.py", Py_file_input, pdict, pdict); //existing

Py_Finalize(); //existing
```